# Concatenating two different lists

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists below.

```
List1 <- list( c("Ford", "Toyota"), c("Chevy", "Dodge", "Jeep"))

List_2 <- list(c("Fusion", "Corolla"), c("Silverado", "Ram", "Renegade"))
```

How can I concatenate the characters in these lists to make a new list? Is there a lapply() solution?

The new list should be as follows.

```
NewList <- list( c("Ford Fusion", "Toyota Corolla"), 
             c("Chevy Silverado", "Dodge Ram", "Jeep Renegade"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `mapply(paste, List1, List_2)`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!